# Mobile device test works for chrome emulator but not phone

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I made a variable with javascript that container a navigation menu called 'header 1' and that one I use for any none mobile devices, the variable 'header 2 ' is for mobile devices.

```
 var phone = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);


    if( phone) {
        document.write(header2);
} else {
    document.write(header1);
}
```

this works with the iphone emulator on chrome but not on my iphone 5, is there anything that i can do?

Comment: Try seeing if "iPhone" (or anything else) is in your iPhone's user-agent (check it at http://whatsmyuseragent.com/).

Comment: Why don't you just check screen size? Are there **no** other mobile devices? Will there **never** be any other mobile devices?

Comment: i checked and iphone is my user agent, anything else i could do to check??

Comment: no, there will be more mobiles devices the iphone is just the one that i am testing it on so i need it to be compatible to more devices than just the iphone